# Instantiating a controller dynamically from a string and attaching it to an element

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing code that lets me create dialogs that have some shared elements (e.g. cancel button, ok button, title) but you can also embed your own template and controller to customise it more. When you create the dialog, you specify the template and controller you want in "template" and "controller" field of a dialog "object" which is passed on to the primary controller for handling dialogs. The dialog controller now needs to embed the template and instantiate the named controller to control the template elements.

The template code I'm trying to use for this part is this:

```
 <ng-include ng-controller="dialog.controller" src="dialog.template">
```

If I remove the controller part, the template appears properly. The controller part generates this error:

```
 "Argument 'dialog.controller' is not a function, got string"
```

How do I instantiate the controller?

Edit: As an example, with the Angular UI modal library you can do this to create a controller:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'dialog_form.html',
    controller: 'DialogFormController',
    resolve: {
      options: function() {
        return dialog;
      }
    }
  });
```

Where the controller field is the name of one of your controllers. How can I copy this functionality to specify my controller with a string instead of a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Controllers are functions, and when you specify ng-controller, Angular will call that function and treat the return result of it as the controller object. That's why controller definitions are done as function-type constructors.

But when this happens there's an additional piece of magic - Angular has a controller Provider that maintains a registry of known controllers, for a variety of reasons. (For instance, it knows what injections they need.) You can't just define a global function and hope it gets called.

If you want to do this, see the ngController documentation which describes this option:

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController:

```
If the current $controllerProvider is configured to use globals (via
$controllerProvider.allowGlobals()), this may also be the name of a
globally accessible constructor function (not recommended).
```

You would use something like this if you wanted the functions supplied to you to be in a global variable, although as noted above it's not recommended.

ngController can also take an expression. In that case it will look for dialog to be a scope variable in the parent controller where this is used, so in there you would need something like:

```
$scope.dialog.controller = function() { /* ... */ };
```

This second technique is less useful if you want to make a generic library, but there are ways around it. For instance, you might have your developers create a dialog collection in $scope or $rootScope:

```
$rootScope.myDialogs['dialog1']['controller'] = function() { };
```

and then use this in your template like:

```
<ng-include ng-controller="myDialogs.dialog1.controller" src="myDialogs.dialog1.template">
```

Finally, you could implement your own ngInclude directive that just did both of those things together from a single argument ('dialog1'). AngularJS Directives give you incredible control over the templates and controllers used to run them.

Comment: So you're saying the way you can do ng-contrller="MyController" where MyController is a string normally, there's no way you can do the same thing but with the string coming from a variable variable. Isn't there a way to grab the controller function associated with the string?

Comment: Functions aren't "associated with" strings - something needs to establish that. This expression will be evaluated and its return result gets used directly. As you say, there's no way to do a variable-variable... But you could throw a `()` onto it to force it to make a function call, as long as the function that gets called returns the right thing: `ng-controller="myDialogs.dialog1.getController()"`. Or the caller can do `$scope.controller = ... GET MY CONTROLLER ..` in its scope before using this directive...

Comment: I've added an edit to the bottom of my post describing what I need and why I think it's possible as another library does this. Thanks for all your effort so far but I really need it to work this way!

Comment: The UI modal library calls $compile to create all this magic. Your example doesn't do this the way you want - it does it in Javascript which is quite easy to do. It's just three lines of code: `var myscope = $rootScope.new();` then `$controller('ControllerName', { $scope: myscope });` then `$compile(element)(myscope);`. That doesn't mean you can do it in a template which is calling $eval and has a completely different behavior. You need a function somewhere to bridge these two.